# Animation looping although Loop Time is unchecked

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict

var anim : Animator;

function Start () {
    anim = GetComponent("Animator");

  }    

function Update () {    
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) 
    {
        anim.SetFloat("hit",1);      
    }
}
```

I have set 'hit' float parameter with 'attack' state, if value of 'hit' > 0.1 , then make transition to 'attack' state from 'Idle state'.

Now problem is, when i click mouse left button, the transition goes from Idle to 'attack' and model perform the desired task, then transition goes from 'attack to Idle' and then again transition goes 'Idle to attack' and goes in loop.

I have set LoopTime, Loop poseto unchecked in animationClip, but still the same is happening.

I understand, the above goes in loop, because the 'hit' parameter never becomes < 0.1 so everytime the condition gets true and transition happens to attack state.

If i add the below line to the above `Update()` function , then transition never happens.

```
anim.SetFloat("hit",0);
```

I dont know where is the problem, what should i do ??, i want when i click mouse left button, then model should hit once and then goes back to Idle state, then again if i click mouse left click, then only it should it..

Any help ?? Please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [trigger](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi35uXW167OAhUCxRQKHZJ1B9UQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.unity3d.com%2FScriptReference%2FAnimator.SetTrigger.html&usg=AFQjCNHI1nF6D78-BzwB2LK-ubeiLA_LPA&sig2=CMd-UudUY7p5rdALLXekvA) for things that happens once and then they should get back to the state they came from like **hitting** or **jumping** or etc

```
anim.SetTrigger("hit");
```

Comment: Hey great, you saved my lot of search and time.. I did not know that.. Anyways Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Single attack animation control parameter should be a **Trigger** instead of float. This way animator will stay in idle.

If you want to use float than after finishing the animation you have to set the float value to **0**. This way parameter doesn't stay greater than 0.1 which is must for float to stay at default animation.

Comment: Thanks, you were also correcr=t.. :-)